# Cursor moving to next cell in DataGridView

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

If I edit a `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` in my `DataGridView` and press the right arrow to move to the end of the string, when i reach the end of the string the cursor will leave the edit mode of that `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` and select the `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` next to it.

Is this default behavior?

Is there a way to keep the caret / cursor inside the current `DataGridViewTextBoxCell` being edited?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    private bool dont_jump;
    private int col_index;
    private int row_index;

    private void dataGridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
    {
        dont_jump = true;
        col_index = e.ColumnIndex;
        row_index = e.RowIndex;
    }

    private void dataGridView1_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (dont_jump)
        {
            dont_jump= false;
            dataGridView1.CurrentCell = dataGridView1[col_index, row_index];
        }
    }
```

Maybe this is working for you